# Android: How to find out reason for "Unfortunately [...] has stopped"?

Tags: android, error-handling, logcat

when I run my Android application with an emulator, it works perfectly, and so it does on my phone, but on another phone, trying to run the app, I always get the "Unfortunately [...] has stopped" error. How can I find out the reason for this error (Using the emulator, I could look it up in LogCat, but not on a real phone)??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a real phone, you can use the tool [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) to view logs on the device itself. You can also connect it to your computer via USB and use the [adb logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) tool, and the logs will be visible from the computer's shell window.

Adb logcat could also be used over a wireless network with a tool like [WiFi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en), should you prefer wireless methods.

Answer (score 1):

[Android Remote Stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/) is a quite useful library/script that allows you to easily add a way for a phone to send its crash logs your way.

Simplest would in this case probably be to add it to a test version you put on the other phone. Since it's not being actively developed (afaik), you may not want to put it in a normal store release build.